# R handling hierarchical data

Tags: r, tidyr

I have this data frame,

df

```
Area Areacode Value
Region1 NA 23
Area1   1 2
Area2   2 1
Area3   3 20
Region2 NA 14
Area1   1 10
Area4   4 4
```

How can we flatten the relationship in Area column, so the output should look like,

```
Area AreaCode Region Value
Area1 1 Region1 2
Area2 2 Region1 1
Area3 3 Region1 20
Area1 1 Region2 10
Area4 4 Region2 4
```

Sorry, forgot to mention that, some are names will have region text in it. But to differentiate them from region, region will not have area code.

Thanks.

Comment: You still do the same thing:`df %>%
    mutate(Region = ifelse(is.na(AreaCode), as.character(Area), NA)) %>%
    fill(Region) %>%
    filter(!is.na(AreaCode))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(Region = ifelse(str_detect(Area, "Region"), Area, NA)) %>%
    fill(Region) %>%
    filter(!str_detect(Area, "Region"))
#   Area Value  Region
#1 Area1     2 Region1
#2 Area2     1 Region1
#3 Area3    20 Region1
#4 Area1    10 Region2
#5 Area4     4 Region2
```

Explanation: Create new column `Region` with entries matching `"Region"` from `Area`. Replace `NA`s with previous non-`NA` entries using `tidyr::fill`, and remove rows matching `"Region"` in column `Area`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Area Value
Region1 23
Area1   2
Area2   1
Area3   20
Region2 14
Area1   10
Area4   4", header = T)
```

---

### Update

With your revised sample data we can do:

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Area Areacode Value
Region1 NA 23
Area1 1 2
'Area region2' 2 1
Area3 3 20
Region2 NA 14
'Area region1' 1 10
Area4 4 4", header = T)

df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(Region = ifelse(is.na(Areacode), Area, NA)) %>%
    fill(Region) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Areacode));
#          Area Areacode Value  Region
#1        Area1        1     2 Region1
#2 Area region2        2     1 Region1
#3        Area3        3    20 Region1
#4 Area region1        1    10 Region2
#5        Area4        4     4 Region2
```

Note this assumes that

1. Rows with regions always have `Areacode = NA`.
2. There is always one `Region` row preceding subsequent `Area` rows.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that area name will have region in it, updated the question.

Comment: @ds_user Your updated question now contains an `AreaCode`; `Area` names are still the same. So what do you mean by *"Sorry forgot to mention that area name will have region in it"*?

Comment: So, some area names will also have 'region' in it. For example, area name can be "Northern Region East".

Comment: @ds_user Please stop changing your problem statement/sample data over and over again; this is very disrespectful towards all those SO respondents who are trying to help based on the data *you* provided originally!

Comment: I changed the question only once, because I missed to add areacode in it. You can even see the revisions of the question. However, sorry for the trouble, thanks for your time and answer. :)

Comment: @ds_user You changed original question statement *and* comments; first you refer to differences in `Area`, then you correct yourself by adding an `AreaCode` (which you could've found out yourself doesn't change anything), then you revise your statement again to include differences in `Area` after all. This is a perfect example for how not to post on SO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169555/discussion-between-ds-user-and-maurits-evers).

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the cumulative sum of the number of `Region`s mentioned in `Area`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(Area = c("Region1", "Area1", "Area2", "Area3", "Region2", "Area1", "Area4"), 
                 Value = c(23L, 2L, 1L, 20L, 14L, 10L, 4L))

df2 <- df %>% 
    # group by cumulative number of "Region" matches
    group_by(region_number = cumsum(grepl('Region', Area))) %>% 
    mutate(Region = Area[1]) %>%    # add Region name for each group
    slice(-1) %>%    # drop Region rows
    ungroup() %>% select(Area, Region, Value)    # drop index and rearrange

df2
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   Area  Region  Value
#>   <chr> <chr>   <int>
#> 1 Area1 Region1     2
#> 2 Area2 Region1     1
#> 3 Area3 Region1    20
#> 4 Area1 Region2    10
#> 5 Area4 Region2     4
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that area name will have region in it, updated the question.

Comment: so `!grepl("Area", Area)` or `is.na(AreaCode)`. You should make your question representative of your issue, though.

Answer (score 1):

using base R solution:

```
do.call(rbind,by(df,cumsum(is.na(df$Areacode)),function(x)cbind(Region=x[1,1],x[-1,])))
     Region  Area Areacode Value
1.2 Region1 Area1        1     2
1.3 Region1 Area2        2     1
1.4 Region1 Area3        3    20
2.6 Region2 Area1        1    10
2.7 Region2 Area4        4     4
```